# How to compute this integral without finding the anti derivative?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$$f(x) = \ln(x^2+1)\cdot e^{\sin(\lvert x \rvert)}\cdot\sin(x)$$
This is the function and I need to compute the integral:
$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x) dx$$
Without finding the anti-derivative of $f(x)$
I don't understand how to approach this question. Can I get a hint?

Comment: Given $a\in \mathbb R$, what do you know about $\displaystyle \int_{-a}^ag$ when $g$ is either even or odd?

Comment: i know that if $g$ is odd then the integral in a symmetric bound is zero. and if $g$ is even then the integral in a symmetric bound equals twice the integral of half this bound... Is $f(x)$ odd or even? How can I know for sure?

Comment: Use the definition. Start with $f(-x)$ and simplify. Hopefully you'll get $f(-x)=-f(x)$, for all relevant values of $x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$I=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)dx=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(-\pi + \pi -x)dx=-I$$

Hence $I=0$

Comment: so this means $f$ is odd, then the integral equals zero because the bound is symmetric?

Comment: Yes. There is nothing special with the $\pi$ there. Any number will still give the same result when the function is odd.

Answer (score 0):

Git Gud already gave you the answer in his/her hint ("comment").

In general, when you see a monstrous integrand like that, immediately check for a "trick question" - you will find that's the case 99% of the time.

Answer (score 0):

Your $f(x)$ is an odd function, then

$$\int_{-a}^a f(x)\ \text{d}x = 0$$